# Bin/Histogram making

Tags: python

Currently I have a program that spits out data points like:

```
52.14535518
6.22793227
6.08643652
18.57737925
12.4697867
31.05047514
31.31070843
56.5758045
6.45830507
6.31006974
6.33210673
12.35320293
18.99089132
31.57124629
6.41475245
```

I want to be able to create 200 bins that are evenly spaced apart and so that when the program spits out the data, whichever range the data point is, the bin adds 1, which will tell me how many points are in each specific range, which I will then be able to plot this into a histogram,

My question is how do I make these 200 bins, and have my program store the data values in each bin, and know how many points are in each bin.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `python`? A more dedicated tool for this is `gnuplot`

Comment: My professor just told me to use python...plus once I have them in bins, I can use  mathplotlip to just make a histogram ez pz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib has the ability to make histograms very easily. See this [histogram demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.html).

An even shorter example would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [52.14535518, 6.22793227, 6.08643652, ...] # <- your data 
num_bins = 200 # <- number of bins for the histogram
plt.hist(data, num_bins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do I need to download the matplotlip.pyplot because as soon as I insert that line I start getting errors, I didn't even add the other parts of the data, So I know the it is the line that is giving the errors.